# Docusign to Salesforce Encryption

Tags: docusign

Good evening, I have a client who needs a secure portal for a customer to submit sensitive info (SSN, W9's,etc.) that will integrate with Salesforce. Docusign seems perfect for this but we want to ensure the encryption during transmission of information meets SOX requirements. Can anybody confirm the type of encryption that docusign uses both in storage and in transmission of data? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The information between Salesforce and DocuSign is transmitted over SSL TLS 1.2.  That means the transport of sensitive information is encrypted over the wire.  The actual question from a SOX compliance you should may be asking is

1. Is DocuSign SOX compliant?  What is the encryption mechanism they store the PII data
2. Is DocuSign logging any PII/Sensitive information in the logs or anywhere where it can be accessed unencrypted?
3. Are you logging the PII information in debug logs of Salesforce in plain text?
4. Are users having access to PII compliant with your organizational SOX policies?

You should reach out to DocuSign on their type encryption mechanisms they follow and review your Salesforce development/configuration practices to look at SOX compliance.